# Radiobuttonlist width in gridview

Tags: css, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBDe2.png)

I am using a radiobuttonlist which is getting data on rowDataBound event in a gridview but it is taking up a lot of space when being rendered. I tried using css-width property defining it in an internal css but that didn't help either. I also tried to define width of td but that didn't help either.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please share this in Codepen or something similar, also provide the expected behavior

Answer (score 0):

Would setting the RB repeat direction to "horizontal" work?

Say this markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover"
            Width="60em">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Province" HeaderText="Province" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Room Clean">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBYesNo" runat="server"
                            RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code to load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If
End Sub


Sub LoadGrid()

    GridView1.DataSource =
        MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName")

    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And results:

[image]

And you can always add a bit of style to space out, or do whatever with the RB list.

Say like this:

[image]

Or maybe this:

[image]

So, I had a old "beat up" to death sytle sheet for above, and it looks like this:

```
    .rMyChoice h1 {
        color: hsla(215, 5%, 10%, 1);
        margin-bottom: 2rem;
    }

    .rMyChoice section {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
    }

    section > div {
        flex: 1;
        padding: 0.5rem;
    }

    .rMyChoice input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {
        display: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }


    .rMyChoice label {

        display: block;
        background: white;
        border: 2px solid hsla(150, 5%, 75%, 1);
        border-radius: 25px;
        padding-left: 8px;
        padding-right: 8px;
        text-align: center;
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px -2px hsla(150, 5%, 65%, 0.5);
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 9px;

    }

    .rMyChoice input[type="radio"]:checked + label, input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
        background: hsla(150, 5%, 75%, 1);
        color: hsla(215, 0%, 100%, 1);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px hsla(150,5%, 75%, 0.75);
    }

    .rMyChoice input[type="radio"]#control_05:checked + label {
        background: red;
        border-color: red;
    }

    .rMyChoice p {
        font-weight: 900;
    }
```

The above needs some love and care, but lacking time, it is posted "as-is".

So, the above rating list (gridview) markup looked like this:

```
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rating">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBYesNo" runat="server" CssClass="rMyChoice"
                            RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                            <asp:ListItem>Poor</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Fair</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Good</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Excellent</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>5&nbsp;star</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this solution didn't work either. Although I used a dropdown list instead of the radiobuttonlist and it worked fine.

Comment: It not clear what you mean by did not work? Do you mean you would rather use a drop down list (that's fine too), but clearly the above screen shots are of working code, and thus the statement does not work is not correct on your part (I did not just suggest, but show working screen shots of using the RB list). So, a VAST difference between not working (the above DOES work) vs that of deciding to use a drop down list. For multiple choices a RB list is nice since the user does not require 2 steps (first step to open the dropdown, and then 2nd step to make a choice). Hence, a RB list is nice.

Comment: My issue was that radiobuttonlist was taking up too much space and I used internal, external and in-line css to adjust the width but nothing worked. SO I finally decided to use a dropdownlist instead of radiobutton.

Comment: No problem - good luck with your project.